# Login into application at startup

Tags: encryption

Short version: I want "Login on program startup" checkbox like [in Skype](http://www.techerator.com/wp-content/uploads/skype_screen_sharing_login.png), for example, but don't know how to protect saved credentials securely.

---

I'm writing client application which, before doing actual requests to server, should be authorized by server. Authorization goes as follows: user fills in standard login dialog, data goes to server via HTTPS and, if it was correct, server sends credentials.

However, entering password each time is disturbing and prevents starting application on system startup. I want to encrypt those credentials and save them on disk. I could not find appropriate encryption key, however.

Key should be, obviously, user-specific (not system-wide!) and reasonably hard to fraud.

For now I just use hash of some HDD info and username and fallback to hash of process environment, if WinAPI call fails (how bad is that?).

I'm writing for Windows using C++/Qt, but any recommendation is welcomed.
Thanks.

---

**upd1**

Ok, to make myself clear:

1. *Required encryption level* is:
   you cannot login by simply copying `credentials.dat` file from one computer to other (or one user folder to other);
2. Keeping *password* secure (which is not stored by application) is user's responsibility.
3. I want to store not the password, but encrypted access token which is `user-id` and `public key` for encrypting communications with server.

From your answers I've understood that my auth. system isn't okay. **I will** reconsider it. And yes, I have access to both, server- and client-side.

For now, I want way to determine machine- and user-unique encryption key, which I can get from OS in runtime to decrypt/encrypt credentials (which is server's answer to email/password entered by user).

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1262081/how-to-encrypt-and-decrypt-a-file-with-qt-c

Comment: It is important to determine "how much" security you have to have. Absolute security is not always trivial to accomplish and is not always required.

Comment: @PlayDeezGames I know *how* and *what* to encrypt, but not sure with what *key*.

Comment: That part's easy! Pick something. Or generate something.

Answer (score 7):

You could do some basic [CHAP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Challenge-Handshake_Authentication_Protocol) style method.

Example:

Client and server have a shared private key for each client user.

- User authenticates first time; server returns a pass token (guid)
- pass token is stored client end.
- Upon "Login on program startup", client requests access.
- Server responds with an "access token" and pre-computes the response (shared private key + access token + pass token)
- client responds by giving the HASH of (shared private key + access token + pass token).
- Pass token is valid until the user logs out.

**EDIT:**
I have done something similar to this for a web service, a little more involved but on the same principles.

Comment: That's great, thanks. I will consider reimplementing auth. system, but now I have other priorities (see `upd1`).

Answer (score 1):

If your application needs to supply the username and password every time, then one way or another, you will be storing them locally (obfuscated somehow, or not).

If you can change the server-side authentication, you could implement an access token-based authentication (as in Darknight's answer), which is what I would favor myself.  That way, you **avoid actually storing passwords on the user's hard drive**.

If you have no control over the server-side, and must supply username and password each time, I would agree with Tom Squires that you should store them as simply as possible.

Why?  Because **to do anything else is to provide a false sense of security to the user**.  For a full argument, you should read ["Plain Text Passwords" on the Pidgin wiki](http://developer.pidgin.im/wiki/PlainTextPasswords).

You should read that page for the full argument, but **to briefly summarize**:

- Any obscured password (anything that isn't hidden behind another
  password) can eventually be un-obscured.
- Not only can it be un-obscured, but a utility could be made that would return you the
  plain-text password with a single button-press.

[**If you have physical access to the computer, passwords aren't relevant.**](https://twitter.com/#!/codinghorror/status/175342480601006081)

Comment: That maybe true for UNIX where files indeed are more secure, but on Windows I want to protect `credentials.dat` file on PC1 from being applicable on PC2 after copying.

Answer (score 0):

You can encrypt it and store the credential info on the client side using any strong and recommended algorithms like SHA-1. But do not store the key used for the encryption on the client side. Let only your server know the key which can decrypt the data.

To keep the client and server in sync, you can ask user to Login/Register into your website and then provide him the link for downloading the application. While creating the application link implant a seed into the application and store the same against the user ID in your server side DB. Use this seed to encrypt and store the credentials on client side and delete the seed after first successful login.